# CSS Grid content centering

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-template
}

header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #28aadc;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.header-fixedWidth {
    height: 320px;
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main {

    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;

}

.main-fixedWidth {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid;
}





@media screen and (min-width: 895px) {
    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 20px;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 988px) {
    
    header {
        max-width: 320px;
    }

    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Call Me Nick</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <div class="header-fixedWidth"></div>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div class="main-fixedWidth"></div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have been tinkering with the CSS grid, and I was attempting to recreate a mock-up of this [website](http://mor10.com/): http://mor10.com/

Notice how the left-hand sidebar remained at a fixed width, while as the main content area grows, the number of columns keeps increasing, without having the content pull to the center.

I was able to recreate the basis of this, but as I keep stretching my browser window, the main content area, rather than stretching, pulls towards the other end of the screen, leaving this large gap between the sidebar and itself.

Can anyone help me correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The grid is working as intended. Content is stretching to its maximum. 
The problem is that your HEADER is narrower than your grid cell.

[image]

Try and use Mozilla Grid inspection tool for css-grid troubleshooting.